# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django

I see tons of questions that are related to this but I can't figure out the solution.

This is on Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.

`data` is a dictionary that contains UTF8 characters. See this line:

`render_to_response('application/app.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Template gets rendered that outputs values from that `data`.

Why does it explode and what can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**: After digging around, part of that `data` contains `lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement`. Basically a XML element that can be queried like a normal dictionary. Values that it produces appear to be proper unicode strings like this: `u'\xae\u2020\xa5\xa8\u02c6\xf8'`

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/web/mysite/current/api/views.py", line 163, in invoice
  return render_to_response('application/app.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 20, in render_to_response
  return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 176, in render_to_string
  return t.render(context_instance)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
  return self._render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
  return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
  bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
  return node.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
  return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
  return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
  bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
  return node.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
  result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
  bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
  return node.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 281, in render
  return nodelist.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
  bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in render_node
  return node.render(context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 880, in render
  return _render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _render_value_in_context
  value = force_unicode(value)

File "/web/mysite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 74, in force_unicode
  s = unicode(str(s), encoding, errors)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: File "/web/mysite/current/api/views.py", line 163, in invoice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should *not* contain UTF-8 characters; it should contain [`unicode`](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)s.

```
{'foo': u'bar'}
```

Comment: Gotcha. I discovered that data contains lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedDataElement and who knows wtf is inside of that.

Comment: Ok, that lxml object has attributes that are accessible like a dict. All values appear to be unicode like this: `u'\xae\u2020\xa5\xa8\u02c6\xf8'`. So any clue what might be blowing it up?

Answer (score 0):

Values in lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement are not really unicode. You can use the following wrapper around your ObjectifiedElement object:

```
from lxml.objectify import ObjectifiedElement, StringElement

class LxmlUnicodeWrapper(object):
    """Avoids UnicodeEncodeError when using ObjectifiedElement in templates."""
    def __init__(self, xml):
        self.xml = xml

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        item = getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "xml"), name)
        if type(item) == ObjectifiedElement:
            return LxmlUnicodeWrapper(item)
        elif type(item) == StringElement:
            return unicode(item)
        else:
            return item
```

then

```
def some_view(request):
    return render_to_response(
        "some_template.html",
        {
            "xml_data": LxmlUnicodeWrapper(your_xml_object)
        },
    )
```